# Showing UIAlertView at END of a For Loop...if NO errors

Tags: ios, for-loop, uialertview

My following code loops through an array for Parse.com to upload from the local datastore to the server.  The issue here, of course, is that it makes an UIAlertView for every successful entry...which gets annoying very quick.  How can I change it so that it will still only show if no errors, but only do it one time at the end of the loop?

```
-(void)uploadToParse {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [self.objects count]; i++) {
        PFObject *entry = [self.objects objectAtIndex:i];


    NSString *imageFileName = [entry[@"FamilyName"] stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    NSLog(@"%@", imageFileName);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageFileName];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);


    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Locationimage.png" data:data];

    [entry setObject:imageFile forKey:@"HousePicture"];


    [entry saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload Complete" message:@"Successfully added your Bible Distribution data." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];


            [entry unpinInBackgroundWithName:@"Share" block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            }];

        }
    }];


    [entry unpinInBackgroundWithName:@"Share" block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        [self loadObjects];
    }];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a `dispatch_group`. They allow you to queue up tasks and only after each task has completed does the completion handler get called.

This should work:

```
-(void)uploadToParse {

    dispatch_group_t uploadGroup = dispatch_group_create();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [self.objects count]; i++) {

        dispatch_group_enter(uploadGroup);
        // ... Your code that sets up the upload task


       [entry saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
           dispatch_group_leave(uploadGroup);
        }];
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(uploadGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        // This gets called after each task completes.
        // Add code to show alert view here.
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was needing.

Answer (score 0):

*Update* - Seems this morning I keep missing important details.  Inside the for loop is doing asynchronous work, so the obvious doesn't work.

**So,** promises provide a clean way to deal with this situation, and there are promise implementations you could use in ios (e.g. promisekit).

Each iteration of the loop would define a promise around its upload operation.  You'd create a compound promise from all of those individual promises.  On success of the compound promise, you'd show your alert.

Comment: I don't think this works because the uploading is asynchronous.

Comment: I need to quick skimming code block :)  Best bet is probably to use promises (something like promisekit)